# How to make this bookmarklet work on Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet test.
Below code works on FireFox but couldn't on Safari 4.0.3.
Does anybody know how to make it work on Safari?

```
javascript:var s = document.createElement("script");
s.text = "document.write('hello');";
s.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with: `s.innerHTML = "document.write('hello');";`

Comment: Thanks Mic. Now I'm testing this code as bookmarklet. So I directly copy & paste the code in url-bar in Safari & Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add document.close() after document.write(...);

```
javascript:(function(){
  s=document.createElement("script");
  s.type="text/javascript";s.text="document.write('Hello88');document.close();"
  document.body.appendChild(s);
 })();
```

Comment: Thanks. But situation is same. I tried below, but it didn't work too.
javascript:s=document.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.text="document.write('Hello88');document.close();" ;document.body.appendChild(s);

Comment: I missed the closing curly brace after document.close();
It works on my Safari 4.0.3 OSX

Comment: Portoalet ,thank you. I already found that thing(and need to add semicolon) but situation is same as bookmarklet.